# How to send props dynamically to styles hook in material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I am trying to add dynamic background images to divs. I am mapping over an array of objects to return divs. How do I add a background image to the div based on the image URL in the object?

Here is the code.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
div: (props) => ({
width: "100px",
height: 0,
paddingBottom: "100px",
backgroundImage: "how do i know which image to pull",
 }),
});

let arr = [
       { photo_url: "some url" },
       { photo_url: "some url" },
       { photo_url: "some url" },
       ];

function Test() {
   const classes = useStyles("how do i send image of that specific object");
   return arr.map((obj) => <div className={classes.div}></div>);
   }
```

EDIT: For the sake of simplicity, I chose to use style prop to add dynamic styles and className prop to add generic styles that are common to all divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send the array to useStyles:

```
   const classes = useStyles(array);
```

Now inside the makeStyles receive the array:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(array=>{
    let divStyles={} 

// create dynamic styles based on the index of the .div class:

  array.forEach((bgUrl,index)=>{
      divStyles[`&:nth-child(${index+1})`]={ // because the index starts at zero
        width: "100px",
        height: 0,
        paddingBottom: "100px",
        backgroundImage: bgUrl,
         }
  })
  return {div:divStyles}
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works but for the sake of simplicity, I chose to use style prop to add dynamic styles and className prop to add generic styles that are common to all divs.